# How do I open the 'launch.json' file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new programmer that started learning Python, but there's something bothering me which I'd like to change.

As I've seen that it is possible to remove the unwanted path from the terminal when executing code, I cannot figure out how to access the Visual Studio Code *launch.json* file and all of the explanations on Google are quite confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette and type `Open launch.json`. And it will open the `launch.json` file for you. If you also can't open `launch.json` then try the way below.

Check if the *.vscode* folder exists in the root folder. If not, then create a new one and create file *launch.json* in that. Now you have *launch.json* for your workspace and you can configure your project.

[image]

Comment: It says "Please first open a folder in order to do advanced debug configuration"

Comment: Check if `.vscode` folder exists in the root folder. If not, then create a new one and create `launch.json` in that. Now you have `launch.json` for your workspace and you can config your project

Comment: I managed to open `launch.json` but I think I opened it as Java and not python. In case you're wondering, I'm trying to remove that unwanted path on the terminal everytime I run a python file.

Answer (score 9):

Note that if Visual Studio Code hasn't created a `launch.json` file for your project yet, do the following:

- Click the `Run | Add Configuration` menu option, and one will automatically be generated for you, and opened in the editor.

NOTE: You have to have a "Folder" open, for this to work. `File | Open Folder...`

Comment: Thanks, a quick help found here

Comment: super quick and easy solution!