# ursina window not opening up on mac OS big sur

Tags: python, ursina

I am starting Ursina out, and I opened the terminal and did pip3 install ursina, and it worked, and now in VS code im running the basic code but no windows are popping up. I am on mac OS Big Sur. This is my code.

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

test_square = Entity(model = 'circle', color = color.red)

app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documents, Ursina doesn't properly work on Mac but I had a mac and I tried to open the window and it worked, you can try reinstalling your IDE and Ursina, if it doesn't work, there's some problem in your MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [docs](https://www.ursinaengine.org), `Ursina` works best on Windows and Linux.

---

**Platforms**

```
     • Windows
     • Linux
```

---

This is weird however, because I ran the code on Mac and got the window properly. Do check if any errors are being thrown, and also check make sure your `launch.json` file looks something like this:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "C:/Users/Sanghun/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe",
        "program": "${file}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
```

If that you've checked these things, it is likely a problem with your OS.

Comment: Dumb question, but where do you find launch.json?

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61764970/14771613

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtual machine, it will work. Ursina only supports Window's and Linux, but a virtual machine should do.

Answer (score 0):

Platforms

• Windows
• Linux
• Mac (not officially supported, but will most likely work)

Answer (score 0):

It mostly works when you're reinstalling setuptools and use PyCharm.